# if $f;R\rightarrow R$ is continuous, and $f(x)=e^{\frac{x^2}{2}}+\int_0^x tf(t)dt$, determine which of the followng is right

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration

$f(x)=e^{\frac{x^2}{2}}+\int_0^x tf(t)dt$
and the given options are

> A) $5<f(\sqrt2)<6$

> b) $2<f(\sqrt2)<3$

> c) $3<f(\sqrt2)<4$

> d) $4<f(\sqrt2)<5$

now,as it's only continuous it's surely integrable and not necessarily diffferentiable so, we have.

$f(x)=e^{\frac{x^2}{2}}+\int_0^x tf(t)dt----1$

$e^{\frac{x^2}{2}}+t \int_0^xf(t)dt-\int_0^x\int_0^xf(t)dt$

but this doesn't help at all
I'm tempeted to differentiate to maybbe obtain a useful expression, so
$$f'(x)=2xe^{\frac{x^2}{2}}+xf(x)$$

which allows me to use integration by parts in $1$

so $f(x)=e^{\frac{x^2}{2}}+\frac{x^2f(x)}{2}-\int_0^x \frac{x^2}{2}f'(x)dx$

which can further be simplified using $f'(x)$

which gives us
$f(x)=e^{\frac{x^2}{2}}+\frac{x^2f(x)}{2}-\int_0^x \frac{x^2}{2}2xe^{\frac{x^2}{2}}+xf(x)dx$

beyond which I'm lost, as the integral seems to become zero

I'd really appreciate a **HINT NOT AN EXPLICIT SOLUTON FOR NOW**

Comment: The right hand side is clearly differentiable by the FTC, so $f$ is in fact differentiable

Comment: I think the answer is A.

Comment: Thanks a lot, everyone!

Answer (score 2):

Here's a hint that may or may not take you there as I haven't worked it out fully yet, but is a good direction to look at:

First,  $f(x)$ is differentiable due to the right hand side of your given equation being differentiable.   Now take your equation you got for $f'(x)$,  this is a standard linear differential equation that can be solved by the method of integrating factors.

Comment: @mathandphysicsforever Follow that hint but correct your small mistake in "$f'(x)=2xe^{\frac{x^2}{2}}+xf(x)$".

Answer (score 1):

HINT:
$$\left(e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}f(x)\right)'=e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}\left(f'(x)-xf(x)\right).$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: You already have
$$f'(x)=2xe^{\frac{x^2}{2}}+xf(x)$$
and hence
$$ f'(x)-xf(x)=2xe^{\frac{x^2}{2}}. \tag1$$
The integral factor of (1) is
$$ \mu(x)=\exp\bigg(\int(-x)dx\bigg)=e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}} $$
and multiplying (1) by $\mu(x)$ gives
$$ \bigg(e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}f(x)\bigg)'=2x. $$
You can do the rest.